# How to know the index of a node selection in a multiple selection?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Suppose you enabled box selection in cytoscapejs or you do something like:

```
cy.nodes().select();
```

when the user clicks a button. So, the user is able to select multiple nodes at once.

When registering the handler for the select event on nodes:

```
cy.nodes().on('select', function(evt){
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to know if the selection of a node is due to:

1. A single selection event (i.e. the user just clicked on a single node)?
2. A multiple selection event (and which index the current node is in this multiple selection)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the events coming in to determine the type of selection (i.e. `tap` versus `tapstart`-`tapdrag`-`tapend` / `tap` versus `box`).  You can keep a counter, declared outside the event callback, to track element indices if you want --- though the indicies won't really mean anything.